# how to increase the size of a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

i have a table "DEPT" ,
let me know how to increase the size of a table.

Comment: Beyond just inserting more rows? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about increasing the size of the TableSpace?

Here is the command for that

```
alter database datafile '<full_file_name>' resize <size>M;
```

example

```
ALTER DATABASE
DATAFILE '/u01/oradata/userdata01.dbf'
RESIZE 500M;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter Tablespace sysaux
ADD DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/prod1/oradata/sysaux02.dbf' SIZE 500M;
```